# Help to plot interval data with R using histogram?

Tags: r, histogram, intervals

I have some data from a questionnaire: How many hours per week did you spend on x?
1-3, 4-6, 7-10, 11-14, >14?

I get this data into R as a column of a dataframe.

```
surv$Q2
#[1] 4 : 11 -14 hours  3 : 7-10 hours    3 : 7-10 hours    4 : 11 -14 hours  3 : 7-10 hours    4 : 11 -14 hours 
#[7] 3 : 7-10 hours    3 : 7-10 hours    3 : 7-10 hours    1 : 1-3 hours     3 : 7-10 hours    2 : 4-6 hours
```

How can I get a histogram of this data (and also is there a function to allow me to easily compute the means?)

Comment: Your first problem is that the intervals have gaps. If someone spent 3.5 hours on *x*, which category are they in? With gaps, you can't really draw a *histogram*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are your data, you can display the frequencies using `barplot`.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 21, 12, 0)
names(x) <- c("1-3", "4-6", "7-10", "11-14", ">14")
x
#  1-3   4-6  7-10 11-14   >14 
#    1     2    21    12     0 
barplot(x)
```

See also the documentation for function `hist`.

Comment: Thanks @javlacalle I can generate a nice bar plot by passing in the column of the dataframe to barplot . However a bar chart is not a histogram. The bars are not joined together (as they should be in a histogram) but have gaps between them. A bigger problem with a bar chart is that the bars are are all the same width whereas in this example I have bins of variable width i.e. the first two intervals are two whereas the next two are three.  I have tried hist in various ways but can't figure out how to get the data in the right format as input to that function.

Comment: You can take the mid-point of each interval as the value for each individual. Then your data are: `x <- c(2, rep(5, 2), rep(8.5, 21), rep(12.5, 12))`. You can plot the histogram indicating the breaks `hist(x, breaks = c(1,3,4,6,7,10,11,14))`. If you set the argument `freq=TRUE` the heights of the bars are equal to the frequencies but be aware that the areas of each bar are not correct since they cannot be equal to relative frequencies with intervals of different width. This is what the warning given by `hist` means if you set `freq=TRUE` in this case.

Comment: Thanks @javlacalle for the reply. This is great. Thank you for you very detailed answer and for using the data I had provided as this now makes perfect sense. I have learned a lot both in terms of how to get data into different formats but also your idea of using the midpoints has made me think that histogram may not even be needed and that a plot could be a better idea.

Comment: @user49242 Yes, it would be better to display the frequencies in a bar plot, good to see it was useful. Please mark the answer as accepted if you think it solved your question, thanks.